# Process download file before save

Tags: react-native, video, react-native-video, react-native-fs

```
import RNBackgroundDownloader from 'react-native-background-downloader';
 
let task = RNBackgroundDownloader.download({
    id: 'file123',
    url: 'https://link-to-very.large/file.zip'
    destination: `${RNBackgroundDownloader.directories.documents}/file.zip`
}).begin((expectedBytes) => {
    console.log(`Going to download ${expectedBytes} bytes!`);
}).progress((percent) => {
    console.log(`Downloaded: ${percent * 100}%`);
}).done(() => {
    console.log('Download is done!');
}).error((error) => {
    console.log('Download canceled due to error: ', error);
});
 
// Pause the task
task.pause();
 
// Resume after pause
task.resume();
 
// Cancel the task
task.stop();
```

I am using the above code. In this i have problem that it downloads a file and save it as it. But i want to encode a file then save it in the internal directly of android folder. Let me know if anyone have a idea to do it. So that i can encode after that file will save.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

How about you download the file and then encode the local file and then save the encoded file and delete the original file.